# How to get Logs from a running batch file

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, cmd

Ok, so in VB, I create and run a batch file. Pretty simple.
The problem is, the batch file starts another program that runs through cmd.
I want to get the output from the cmd program the batch file starts, any ideas?

Someone earlier said that i could do somthing with command parameters, 
could you explain that to me if that is right?

Answer (score 1):

I ask that you are not particularly harsh in giving a downvote becasue the question is worded very vaugue. To me it sounds like you are looking for something like this.

```
@echo hello >> log.txt
```

What this is going to do is force the output of whatever command you have typed to be sent into a text file named log.txt.
I have created a very useful application where I record network activity on my home network and save it into a log file using the same overall idea so I know it can be useful.